# SSH connection to OpenWRT and RSYNC to connected device

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, ssh-tunnel, openwrt

I have possibility to use 2,5 GB Internet link in geographically distant location for backup needs. So I want to use TP-Link Gigabit router WR-1043WD with OpenWRT installed on it. There is Seagate Personal Cloud 3,5'' 4TB connected to router over Ethernet cable. Seagate Personal Cloud has possibility to run RSYNC client and server, but there is no SSH on it. I dont want to install alternative software on Seagate Personal Cloud because of warranty.
But of course it is very simple to run SSH and RSYNC on OpenWRT.
My idea is to RSYNC over SSH data from home server to the distant location mentioned before.
My question is. How can I tunnel RSYNC traffic over SSH to router and than RSYNC without SSH data with Seagate Personal Cloud in clear (unencrypted) form?